# How to test range query performance using db_bench of rocksdb?

Tags: database, rocksdb

I want to test the range query performance of rocksdb by using rocksdb's db_bench, but I don't know how to config, and I can't find any method on Google. Can you help me? Thank you!

There are many benchmark args of rocksdb's db_bench, such as 'readrandom' and 'seekrandom', and I don't know which arg supports range query.

Answer (score 0):

In db_bench the benchmark is called "seekrandom". There are different options for specifying what kind of scan is done after each Seek(). The most basic one is -seek_nexts to call Next() the specified number of times. (This question is duplicated on GitHub: https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/issues/12195)

Comment: I am the one who raised this issue, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

To test the range query performance of RocksDB using db_bench, you'll want to focus on arguments that allow you to perform range scans. Typically, in db_bench, the readwhilescanning argument is used for this purpose.

Here's a brief guide on how to configure it:

**Specify the Benchmark:** Use --benchmarks=readwhilescanning. This benchmark performs range queries.

**Set Up the Database:** Before running the benchmark, ensure your database has enough data to test the range queries effectively.

**Customize Parameters:** You can adjust various parameters like the number of queries, the size of the database, etc., to suit your test requirements.

Run db_bench: Execute the db_bench command with the specified arguments.

Example Command:

```
./db_bench --benchmarks=readwhilescanning --num=100000 --reads=1000 --value_size=1024 --histogram=1 --db=path/to/db
```

This command runs the readwhilescanning benchmark on a database located at path/to/db, with 100,000 keys, performing 1,000 read operations, and values of size 1024 bytes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).